# Understanding the bottom-up rod cut implementation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

In [Introduction to Algorithms(CLRS)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), Cormen et al. talk about solving the Rod-cutting problem as follows(page 369)

```
EXTENDED-BOTTOM-UP-CUT-ROD(p, n)
    let r[0...n] and s[0....n] be new arrays
    r[0] = 0

    for j = 1 to n:
        q = -infinity   

        for i = 1 to j:
            if q < p[i] + r[j - i]:  // (6)
                q = p[i] + r[j - i]
                s[j] = i
        r[j] = q

    return r and s
```

Here `p[i]` is the price of cutting the rod at length i, `r[i]` is the revenue of cutting the rod at length i and `s[i]`, gives us the optimal size for the first piece to cut off.

My question is about the outer loop that iterates `j` from `1` to `n` and the inner loop `i` that goes from `1` to `n` as well.

On line 6 we are comparing `q` (the maximum revenue gained so far) with `r[j - i]`, the maximum revenue gained during the previous cut.

When `j = 1 and i = 1`, it seems to be fine, but the very next iteration of the inner loop where `j = 1 and i = 2`, won't `r[j - i] be r[1 - 2] = r[-1]`?

I am not sure if the negative index makes sense here. Is that a typo in CLRS or I am missing something here?

I case some of you don't know what the rod-cutting problem is, here's an [example](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F09/dynamic.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the key: `for i = 1 to j`

`i` will begin at 1 and increase in value **up to but not exceeding** the value of `j`.

`i` will never be greater than `j`, thus `j-i` will never be less than zero.

Comment: Code labs - Yup! A stupid oversight. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem, we all overlook things sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Variable i will not be greater than variable j because of the inner loop and thus index r become never less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the conditions in the inner for loop. In that, the value of i goes only upto j. So if it exceeds j, the loop will be terminated. Hence no question of the negative indices you mentioned.