# Dynamic Programming - Rod Cutting while keeping tab on indices at which the cut was made

Tags: python-2.7, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, memoization

In the classical rod-cutting Dynamic programming problem - where do I make cuts on a rod of lenght n to maximize the price I obtain by selling either the full rod, or parts of it thereof.  See also, problem statement here for details -[Understanding the bottom-up rod cut implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507292/dynamic-programming-rod-cutting-problem)

**How do I keep a tab of the indices - ie where in the original rod did I make the cuts ?**
I don't seem to have a fair understanding of knowing how to keep indices at which the rod was eventually cut.
Here is my code -:

```
# price is dict of revenue we get for the corresponding rod-length
price={1:1,2:5,3:8,4:9,5:10,6:17,7:17,8:20,9:24,10:30}

def cut_rod(n,price):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    revenue=-999
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
  ##I do this, since my price[1] ie the keys to the price dictionary start from 1...n
        revenue=max(revenue,price[i]+cut_rod(n-i,price))
    return revenue

n=4 # print the maximum revenue we earn for rod of length 4
revenue=cut_rod(n,price)
print "revenue for rod of length %d is %d" %(n,revenue)
```

**For the rod of length 4, I make cuts on 2 and 2 (ie midway) - how we do memorize these indices ?**

Edit : I have an approximate idea that I need to keep tab of all revenues seen so far, with the corresponding cut locations - but I just seem to get lost in the main call - should I be storing this between the subsequent calls in a dict structure and just look it up later. 
 I also think that the indices will be a dict(for look-ups later) with "list" as values, since for some combinations of rod length - we may cut more than once.

+1 for intuitive explanation, should you be answering .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics. This is a programming site.

Comment: You may have a better luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/ or at one of its siblings.

Answer (score 1):

So I've modified your code a bit to do two things:

1) Return "indicies" or cuts where the max val was found.

2) Store previously calculated results in a dict

```
import copy
price={1:1,2:5,3:8,4:9,5:10,6:17,7:17,8:20,9:24,10:30}
max_price = {}

def cut_rod(n,price):
    if n==0:
        #We are returning 0 and the empty list for a rod of size 0 as we don't cut
        #This is our base case
        return 0,[]
    revenue=-999
    #If we have already calculated the max price for the length, return price and indicies
    if n in max_price.keys():
        return max_price[n][0],copy.copy(max_price[n][1])
    cuts = []
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
            #Get the revenue and indicies from the smaller piece
        smaller_revenue,smaller_cuts =  cut_rod(n-i,price)
            #If we get a better price, set the indicies and revenue for the length
        if smaller_revenue + price[i] > revenue:
            smaller_cuts.append(i)
            cuts = smaller_cuts
            revenue = smaller_revenue + price[i]
    #store the calculated max results for rod of length n
    #need to copy to avoid linking
    max_price[n] = (revenue,copy.copy(cuts))
    return revenue, cuts
```

So all we are doing is using DP to remember where we cut for the max price for size `n`. We have to copy.copy() to eliminate accidentally modifying lists we made "permanent".

For example,

If we call `cut_rod(1,price)`

it will eventually call `cut_rod(0,price)`

which will return `0 and []`

Our revenue will be -999, so `price[1] + 0 will be > -999`

The cuts for 1 will be [1].

Feel free to run

```
n = 10
revenue,cuts = cut_rod(n,price)print "revenue for rod of length %d is %d" %(n,revenue)
print "Cuts were sizes:"
print cuts
print max_price
```

To see length of sub rods and the full dict.

Output:

```
revenue for rod of length 10 is 30

Cuts were sizes:
[10]
#key = rod length, value = (revenue, [where cuts were made])
{1: (1, [1]), 2: (5, [2]), 3: (8, [3]), 4: (10, [2, 2]), 5: (13, [3, 2]), 6: (17, [6]), 7: (18, [6, 1]), 8: (22, [6, 2]), 9: (25, [6, 3]), 10: (30, [10])}
```